# How do I compare each row with all the others and if it's the same I concatenate to a new dataframe? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Country': ['A',  'A', 'A' ,'B', 'B'],'Capital': ['CC',  'CD','CE','CF','CG'],'Population': [5, 35, 20,34,65]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Country',  'Capital',  'Population'])
```

I want to compare each row with all others, and if it has the same Country, I would like to concatenate the pair into a new data frame (and transfor it into a new csv).

```
new_data =  {'Country': ['A',  'A','B'],'Capital': ['CC',  'CD','CF'],'Population': [5, 35,34],'Country_2': ['A', 'A' ,'B'],'Capital_2': ['CD','CE','CG'],'Population_2': [35, 20,65]}

df_new = pd.DataFrame(new_data,columns=['Country',  'Capital',  'Population','Country_2','Capital_2','Population_2'])
```

NOTE: This is a simplification of my data, I have more than 5000 rows and I would like to do it automatically
I tried comparing dictionaries, and also comparing one row at a time, but I couldn't do it.
Thank you for the attention

Comment: Why in the output there are only `2 rows` for the country `A`? If you wanna compare each row with every other row then, there are `3 possible` combinations not `2`.

Comment: And what if i want also do all combinations posible ... in this case I would have to have a third row in the new df with the Country =A and Capital = CC; Country_2 = A and Capital = CE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df.join(df.groupby('Country').shift(-1), rsuffix='_2')\
...   .dropna(how='any')
  Country Capital  Population Capital_2  Population_2
0       A      CC           5        CD          35.0
1       A      CD          35        CE          20.0
3       B      CF          34        CG          65.0
```

This pairs every row with the next one using `join` + `shift` − but we restrict shifting only within the same country using `groupby`. See what the groupby + shift does on its own:

```
>>> df.groupby('Country').shift(-1)
  Capital  Population
0      CD        35.0
1      CE        20.0
2     NaN         NaN
3      CG        65.0
4     NaN         NaN
```

Then once these values are added to the right of your data with the `_2` suffix, the rows that have `NaN`s are dropped with `dropna()`.

Finally note that `Country_2` is not repeated as it’s the same as `Country`, but it would be very easy to add

Answer (score 0):

To get all combinations you can try:

```
from itertools import combinations,chain

df = (
    pd.concat(
        [pd.DataFrame(
            np.array(list(chain(*(combinations(k.values,2))))).reshape(-1, len(df.columns) * 2),
            columns = df.columns.append(df.columns.map(lambda x: x + '_2')))
        for g,k in df.groupby('Country')]
        )
)
```